# How to save records and get records on behalf of another user

Tags: django, django-1.5

I'm working on a **Django 1.5** Project.

The application contains the user hierarchy of

```
Owner
Admin
Viewer
```

> - Owner owns all the data in the database.
> - Admin users are created by the owner and have different login credentials. Can add/edit/delete data under Owner.
> - Viewer users are created by the owner and have different login credentials. Can view data created under the Owner.

**Users** model have a field `is_shared` (boolean) to identify main user and shared user and `access_level` is mapped in another model **MultiUser**.

I have thought of to implement it in the way

1. Update all viewsets and put check in `get_queryset`.
2. where first check will be made if user has `is_shared=True`
3. then check in **MultiUser** model,
4. get the `user` from **MultiUser** and then filter records on behalf of the user.

But this will require changes throughout the application viewsets.

**Is there a way to do this without making changes to the whole application.
May be `middleware`.**

> Edit 2: MultiUser model

```
class MultiUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner_user')
    shared_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='shared_user')
    access_level = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you also provide the code for your viewset and MultUser model.

Comment: Also I'm confused. `viewsets` are part of django-rest-framework and not django. correct me?

Comment: `viewsets` are part of `DRF`

Comment: Added `MultiUser` models. Viewset is not specific, there are many viewsets already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a middleware with content

```
class MultiUserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        """
        Check if user profile is is_shared=True
        If user is a shared user, get owner user from multi user
        and assign owner user to request.user

        Any multi user profile created by the owner user will work on behalf of the owner user
        """

        user = request.user
        if not user.is_anonymous():
            # if request.path in settings.MUTLIUSER_ALLOWED_PATH:
            #     return None

            # Search using wildcard
            if any(fnmatch(request.path, p) for p in settings.MUTLIUSER_ALLOWED_PATH):
                return None

            try:
                if user.profile.get().is_shared:
                    owner = MultiUser.objects.filter(shared_user=user)[0].user
                    request.user = owner
            except:
                return None

        return None
```

This middleware check for if the user's account is a shared user based on `is_shared` and then change the request.user with the owner user object. This also prevents changing the request owner for specific paths defined in the **settings** file (Ex., profile, change_password, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating all viewsets, you could use a single base class to deal with.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class BaseView(View):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_shared:
            #some is_shared value
            u = MultiUser.objects.filter(user=request.user)
            if u.exists():
                return #some multiuser value
            else:
                return #some non multi user value

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class MyView(BaseView):
    def get(self, request):
        q = self.get_queryset
        #view logic
        return HttpResponse('result')

class MyView2(BaseView):
    def get(self, request):
        q = self.get_queryset
        #view logic
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

Comment: There are lot of views which are extending other custom views or generic DRF views. Your solution will require to update all viewsets to extend `BaseView`

Comment: "There are lot of views which are extending other custom views". You might be having some redundant code. Please signin and share your `views.py` here: https://gist.github.com/
I will help then.